# How to get column name from the table with particular value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a table like :

```
.............................
id  | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed |
.............................
1   | 0   | 1   | 1   |  1  |
.............................
```

Now i am getting all the column name from this query:

```
DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('weak');
```

> it returning me the array of all columns name

but i want those column name which have the 1 value how can i get those column which have 1 value in laravel..any anyone please help me related this ??

Comment: What are the numbers representing?

Comment: 0 not access and 1 access so i need only 1 value related columns..

Comment: Normalise your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: can you explain briefly @Pooja

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries read more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the second parameter:

```
$object = DB::table('weak')->first();
$columns = array_keys((array)$object, 1);
```

The result will be:

```
['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']
```

Comment: $res['access'] =DB::table('weak')->first()->toArray();
                                  $columns = array_keys($array, 1);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($columns);exit;  i did this but getting error   Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()

Comment: @Pooja sorry, `toArray()` will work with model. Use `(array)` as I've shown in updated answer.

Comment: now i did this   res['access'] =DB::table('weak')->first();
                                  $columns = array_keys($res['access'], 1);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($columns);exit;     now its returning me the error array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: @Pooja please double check your code. I've tested it and it works fine. The `(array)` will convert an object to an array.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to build a Custom query using the IF function

```
SELECT
   (IF(table.Sun == 1) table.Sun,)
   (IF(table.Mon == 1) table.Mon,)
   ......
   table.id
FROM table
```